# file_get_contents("php://input") empty after ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I'm hesitating to ask, but I haven't found any solution. After send data in php file in ajax function, when I try to catch the data in php file, the data are lost. But, yester I maked a similar function who run without problem. 
This is the ajax part:

```
$http({  
          url: 'PDO/Companion.php',
          data: {
              Companion : Companion,
              Companion : statut
          },
          method: 'POST',
          headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}


      }).then(function (response) {// on success
          $scope.name=undefined;
          $http.get('js/controller/upPartenaire.php').success(function(data) {
              $scope.result = data;
              console.log(data);
          }), function(msg){
              console.log("ça")
              alert(msg);
          };
```

And the php part:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
echo json_encode($request);
```

In my project I use PHP only for the ajax part to do SQL queryI also to catch data with $_POST but nothing

Comment: Have you done your due diligence and debugged the ajax calls with the browser developer console and network tabs? Are you positive its sending data, and there are no console errors?

Comment: You should also include the code where the `var Companion` and `statut` are defined, and also explain why you are trying to send the data keyname of `Companion` twice. And lastly, if you have the jquery library loaded, why not simplify a lot of that by using `$.post`? [Jquery .post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type to json and make JSON stringify like

```
$http({  
      url: 'PDO/Companion.php',
      data: JSON.stringify({
          Companion : Companion,
          Companion : statut
      }),
      method: 'POST',
      headers : {'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=utf-8'}


  }).then(function (response) {// on success
      $scope.name=undefined;
      $http.get('js/controller/upPartenaire.php').success(function(data) {
          $scope.result = data;
          console.log(data);
      }), function(msg){
          console.log("ça")
          alert(msg);
      };
```

Comment: if you are goint to use `x-www-form-urlencoded` the best approach is to use `$_POST['Companion']`. Another thing is that you are sending Companion twice on the post

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. Consider changing php code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");

parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input', false , null, -1 , 
$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'] ), $postdata);

echo json_encode($postdata);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I try your solution, but it doesn't run, I have two error message:
Notice: Undefined index: CONTENT_LENGTH
and
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in line 5

Comment: $_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH']  should be available if you are making a  post request. Also, i will edit my answer for the updated solution.

Comment: Okay maybe the php part is not the problem but the ajax part.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue before 
**My Solution** 
i have convert the data into urlencoded format and pass into the post request.

```
url = Object.keys(data).map(function(k) {
    return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k])
}).join('&')
```